# plotly : horizontal bar plot not recognizing / displaying trace2

Tags: python, plotly, data-visualization, plotly-dash

I have a graph component for horizontal barplot that is wrapped in a `callback` function and returns a figure.

```
trace1 = go.Bar(
            x = [-2, -1.5, -1.2, -1, -0.5],
            y = ["C", "0", "I", "D", "R"],
            orientation = "h",
            marker = {
                "color": 'rgba(58, 71, 80, 0.6)'
            },
        )

        trace2 = go.Bar(
            x = [2.2, 1.8, 1.3, 0.9, 0.5],
            y = ["C", "0", "I", "D", "R"],
            orientation = "h",
            marker = {
                "color": 'rgba(246, 78, 139, 0.6)'
            },
            yaxis = "y2"
        )

        data = Data([trace1, trace2])

        layout = {
                    "xaxis": {'title': 'Percentage change', 'range': [-3, 3]},
                    "title": "Diagram",
                    "width": 862,
                    "height": 680,
                    "barmode": "stack",
                    "autosize": True,
                    "showlegend": False,
        }

        return{'data':data, 'layout':layout}
```

My plot didn't plot the negative side of the barplot. Basically, I would like to use color to separate values on either side of 0.

[image: barplot]

Comment: In the second graph, we need to add the base point `base=0` and remove `yaxis=y2`